# Why is this question deleted after only 11 minutes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

Regarding this question:
[Send message as UDP traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456889/send-message-as-udp-traffic)

From what I understand, it's unclear and therefore correctly closed. But what's the reason for instantly deleting it? I would assume the OP has still a chance to improve it, it might become answerable. Is there anything I overlooked?

Comment: Well, I can't say I'm sorry to see it go.  It was unclear for multiple reasons, and I suspect that further attempts to assist would result in impractical, hand-holding exchanges with a help-vampire:(

Comment: Haha, I'm not sorry either, but still curious what's the reason for this action, as I *thought* it would be common practice to keep something like this for some time, so the OP **could** fix it?

Comment: @pnuts without assuming the person who actually did delete would answer, this was indeed open for discussing *possible* reasons. Now, you could still discuss whether this reasoning is a good one. In any case, I didn't request it to be undeleted, I was just wondering.

Comment: @pnuts according to [tag:support]'s tag wiki, this isn't the case.

Comment: @pnuts deletion is a feature, thoughts about when exactly deletion is a good course of action isn't. I don't have any doubts about how deletion works.

Comment: @pnuts so? how does this make it a support request? You can still discuss whether this action was appropriate, wrt to the linked example.

Comment: @pnuts I wonder what your problem is, but I'll probably stop caring. I don't see any name calling here, I just observed some action I found questionable and wanted to know the reasons behind. Asking about it is of course asking for discussion, it's not a technical feature but more about guidelines.

Comment: Because on StackOverflow, some people think they are gods and have all the power. :(

Comment: @pnuts: Eh? There is no name calling, and the second question is not substantively different from the first (in this particular instance). On the contrary, providing a specific example brings context to the query. If you feel that you cannot answer this question without resorting to name calling, perhaps you'd be better off skipping it!

Comment: I remember questions being deleted within fewer minutes without letting OP to edit.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I deleted it. Sometimes, when closing a question, if I don't have confidence it is likely to be edited to be useful (on topic) I will delete it immediately. It's a judgement call.

Based on the latest 5 questions the OP posted:

[Send message as UDP traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456889/send-message-as-udp-traffic)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452428/hardware-receive-timestamp-linux

[Linking C file with two libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51414514/linking-c-file-with-two-libraries)

[Dynamically linked library in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413301/dynamically-linked-library-in-makefile)

[cJSON field does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393848/cjson-field-does-not-exist)

The OP is not demonstrating a pattern of revised, on topic or upvoted posts.

The OP can flag a mod to have it undeleted. However, I've undeleted it, to give the OP a chance to edit it, without needing to mod flag.

Comment: instant "accept" here because it's a straight forward answer: the decision is based on the user's immediate question history, thanks.

Comment: Yeah - I guessed there was history.   I don't do 'meta effect', so I will not be voting on the other, doubtless bad, questions:)

Comment: I wondered about the bold disclaimer as well ;) Is this really a thing people go on targeted votes when some bad questions are linked on meta? Well, I won't either :)

Comment: 'I've undeleted it, to give the OP a chance to edit it' well, you're glass-half-full mod today:)   If anything useful is added, I'll eat my dog.

Comment: Poor pooch. He deserves better

Comment: @FelixPalmen the meta effect..

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh, Bailey is safe enough on this one;)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know. I feel sorry for people who struggle.

Comment: I love the downvotes. I will also like to see the status of the question in 2 weeks time when it's eligible for roomba

Comment: I have no clue why this answer was downvoted, unless it was for the 'meta effect' warning?  Oh well - voters....[shrug]

Comment: Well I didn't vote here, I was merely interested in the reason. Now that I know it, I see pros (cleaner state of the page) and cons (taking away the chance to improve) for deleting so soon. No clear opinion on my part :)

Comment: +1. A question can be edited if it's not deleted by the OP. Although next time you should probably leave a templated comment → "Because the question is off-topic, I am going to delete it. If you improved your question and want it to be undeleted, feel free to moderator flag it so a moderator can undelete it."

Comment: @user202729 a splendid idea.

Comment: @MartinJames: perhaps the DV's are due to disagreement with the moderator's initial action of deleting the question immediately without notification

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels maybe.  I guess we'll never know for sure, (and long may that be the case:).

Comment: OP self-deleted so I guess the undeletion didn't help any

Comment: OK, I will let Bailey, (our dog), know that he's not going to be shoved in a bun and covered with onions and mustard..

Comment: @Martin: Because surely this is the roomba's job (or _maybe_ the community), not for one moderator to do unilaterally.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit mods are allowed to use good judgement and use the tools they've been provided with. They are held accountable. As Shog said, you can use your judgement, as long as you can stand up and justify it on meta with good reason. It takes one gold badge holder to dupe close, 3 high rep users to delete, what hard is there for one community elected and entrusted mod to use discretion and delete?

Comment: @YvetteColomb I'm not disputing that you're _allowed_ to ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit are we agreeing on something ;) or is that a miscommunication? :D

Comment: @YvetteColomb Note down the time and place!

Comment: the problem with the human condition is we see ourselves by our intentions at times and not from an outside perspective